# creating custom command in /usr/bin doesnt work

Tags: linux, bash, command

I have a script I want to be able to execute as a command. I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84688) post that works for simple scripts, but mine does not seem to work.
my script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
alias symlinkall="readarray -d '' array < <(find -type f -print0)
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" > file.txt
IFS='

'
mkdir all
for i in `cat file.txt`; do
g=`echo "$i" | tr '/' '_'`
f="${g:2}"
#echo "ln -s \"$i\" \"$f\""
ln -s "$PWD/$i" "$PWD/all/$f"
done
rm file.txt all/file.txt"
```

when I try to run it as a custom command it seems to get messed up on printf as it creates the file but only writes one "n" to it even though the array has correct file paths in it. when I run it line by line everything works just fine.

with set -x i get this output:

```
+ symlinkall
cat: file.txt: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/symlinkall: line 11: alias: -s: not found
/usr/bin/symlinkall: line 11: alias: "": not found
/usr/bin/symlinkall: line 11: alias: ""
ln -s /media/pi/HDD1/smb-share/Bilder/folder/ /media/pi/HDD1/smb-share/Bilder/folder/all/
done
rm file.txt all/file.txt: not found
```

Edit: managed to get it to work, apparently in when executed in terminal it cat creates missing files while in a script it does not

Comment: Do you get any errors or output at all?

Comment: Taht is your full script?  The first line should probably be `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Why are you using a temporary file?  `printf ... | while read i` will do the same.

Comment: And why not `for file in "${array[@]}"` -- no need to print the contents of the array at all, as that destroys the safety you gain with `find ... -print0`

Comment: The folder and file do get created, no errors or output though. As for why i did it that way: it works

Comment: How do you run it? How do you inspect the file given that the script deletes it?

Comment: forgot to mention it doesnt get deleted. I run it via the filename of the script in /usr/bin. here is the exact file https://imgur.com/x2XZ341

Comment: @Daniel I'm guessing the script is named `symlinkall`, and that you have an alias named `symlinkall` left over that gets called instead of your script. If you run `/usr/bin/symlinkall` you will run the actual script and see that it fails with a series of errors. In the future, please avoid saying "my exact script is" and then posting something that is not your exact script. It's very misleading.

Comment: You should not be using an alias at all here. Remove the `alias symlinkall="` and the final `"`, open a new shell and make sure `type symlinkall` says `symlinkall is /usr/bin/symlinkall` and not `is aliased to ..`. Then try again.